# How to Convert the Cognos ReportPath () Component into Breadcrumbs?

Tags: cognos

I'd like to know how to turn the Cognos ReportPath () component into breadcrumbs. For Example:

**ReportPath ():**
/content/folder[@name='My Department']/folder[@name='My Application']/report[@name='My Report']

**Breadcrumbs:**
My Department > My Application > My Report

My specific environment uses Microsoft SQL Server. Unfortunately, the **Layout Calculation** expression builder does not allow the ***replace()*** function. I've tried using multiple combinations of *substring*, *position*, and *character_length* functions to manipulate the Cognos ReportPath () component, but I cannot wrap my head around how to make this work.

Please share the method you use to turn the Cognos ReportPath () component into breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 0):

There are no recursive calls in the layout expressions, which means there is no real dynamic way to do this within that realm.  The Cognos macro language on the other hand is quite good at doing this via the split and join functions, however these are only applicable to data items and prompts, not layout expressions.

If this only needed in HTML format, you could just use Javascript to grab the ReportPath via ID or divs, then manipulate it after.

If its required in excel or PDF, you would use that same Javascript to populate a value prompt, thus allowing for display and macro/data validation.

Its not pretty but it works